# Set unicoin amount

Tags: unicoins

I've tried

```
StackExchange.uc.setBalance(99999999);
```

and it was nothing more than a visual thing.

Also, I bought the power up and now I want an inspirational answer. Because I fell that the unicorns would appreciate the going.

Q: Is there a faster way to mine unicoins or set them so I can get ALL the unicoins.

**EDIT:**

I feel like the unicorns aren't happy with the decision I've made of asking. They're outside my house.

**Unicorn edit:**

We've got him. Don't come looking, he's ours now.

Comment: Mining unicorns is definitely too slow.

Comment: they're the second worst things to mine in the whole world. Also I think they should keep the comic sans light blue comments, it makes me feel at home.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/441860/253389

Comment: This has made me a happy person. Thanks @staticx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to the mining page, execute the following code in your console, just keep moving your mouse over the rocks.

```
$('#uc-rockcanvas').mousemove(function(event) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           var mousedownEvent = document.createEvent ("MouseEvent");
           mousedownEvent.initMouseEvent ("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 
                                          event.screenX, event.screenY, event.clientX, event.clientY, 
                                          event.ctrlKey, event.altKey, event.shiftKey, event.metaKey, 
                                          0, null);
           event.target.dispatchEvent (mousedownEvent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, although my lifespan to unicoins ratio still isn't satisfactory.